# Load dependencies only for one function

Tags: r, plotly, devtools, roxygen2

I am creating a package with a few functions. Only one auxiliary function needs `plotly`.

However when I install using `devtools` I get a note `unused arguments in layout(yaxis = ay,...` Then I read [Hadley's article about `imports` vs `depends`](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html). Using import doesn't remove the note, but adding `plotly` with `depends` in the NAMESPACE-file solves the issue.

Next I read the paragraph about 'Search Path'. Here Hadley states that

> You should never use require() or library() in a package: instead, use the Depends or Imports fields in the DESCRIPTION

My issue now is that the function which uses `plotly` is more of an add-on to the package. All other (more important) functions work with base-R. 
Therefore I want to use `plotly` only for the one function which needs it.

1. Is that possible without creating a note during `install`?
2. Why are `require` or `library` so bad inside a package?
3. Would it be okay to use `requireNamespace` and then `require` afterwards?

Here is some sample code:

```
#' Some plotly function
#'
#' Some very long description
#'
#' @param x_vec A numeric vector
#' @param y_vec A numeric vector
#' @keywords Some keywords
#' @return A plotly object
#' @export
#' @examples

debugMinEx<-function(x_vec,y_vec){

ay <- list(title = "",zeroline = FALSE,showline = FALSE,
           showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE,
           scaleanchor="x",scaleratio=1) ## empty axis
ax <- list(title = "",zeroline = FALSE,showline = FALSE,
           showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE) ## empty axis
my_legend<-list(font = list(family = "sans-serif", size = 14, color = "#000000"),
                x = 0, y = -0.05,orientation = "h")

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=x_vec,y=y_vec,
            type='scatter',mode='lines') %>%
  layout(yaxis = ay,xaxis=ax,
          legend = my_legend)
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use `Suggests` instead of `Imports`: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages

Comment: so best practice would be to use `Suggests` and to e.g. use `plotly::plot_ly` functions inside an `requireNamespace`-if clause? Isn't calling `plotly::` making the function slower? Or does my memory betray me :P

Comment: Every function call, even `::`, has overhead, probably on the order of microseconds. If you are running this function in a loop millions of times, you'll notice a difference of a second or two. But my guess is you're not generating millions of plotly plots...

Comment: The overhead from the `if` clause is larger than from `::`. I'd not use such a construct for performance-critical functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *Suggests* for this.

You can read about it in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages) or in Hadley's [Package Basics: Decription](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html).  In both cases, the recommendation is

- The optional dependency goes in the `Suggests` field of your package `DESCRIPTION`.
- Use `if (requireNamespace)` in the function to test it the package is there.

Something like this:

```
if (requireNamespace("plotly", quietly = TRUE)) {
      # do your plotly stuff
   } else {
      # do non-plotly stuff
      # maybe as simple as stop("Please install plotly to use this function")
   }
```

As for whether you can use `require` after `requireNamespace` - that seems pointless. Hadley's recommendations seem to be pretty clear to use `requireNamespace("plotly")` to load the package and subsequently use `plotly::` to call the needed functions.

If you'd prefer to ignore this advice, then just do `require` the first time. Using `requireNamespace` followed by `require` is redundant. As explained in your link, `requireNamespace` loads a package without attaching it. `require` both loads and attaches.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. That clears most of that foggy confusion. I assume not using `require` or `library` is meant to increase transparency for the user. I mean using e.g. `require` inside a function might cause confusion, since the user might try to attach the package again, right?

Comment: Yes. A couple paragraphs down in the Imports vs Depends link: *"a good package... minimises changes to the global environment (including the search path)"*. Using `library()` or `require()` changes the search path, which the user may not want. Using `requireNamespace` and `::` gives the same result to the user without changing their search path.